# What is the minimum amount of RAM requirement for zephyr?

Tags: zephyr-rtos

I can found the information on the official website.
I need this information for BRAM instantiation in my FPGA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the response on the official website :
https://www.zephyrproject.org/what-is-zephyr/

The minimum amount of memory is **8kB**:

> Runs on systems as small as 8 kB of memory to more than 512 kB

Answer (score 1):

Just a fresh update

Reference ROM size: 2-3KB

https://docs.zephyrproject.org/2.6.0/samples/basic/minimal/README.html